# How to Query and Store data from an external api on the Google Cloud Platform and make it available to users of an app

Tags: android, json, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-firestore

I'm in the middle of learning and exploring the *Google Cloud Platform* / *Firebase* for my App development ambitions, having fun and be excited about what is possible, I can't see to find a tutorial / article what describes what I want. Maybe I'm just overlooking it, with so much info thrown at me, but hey :-)

---

**Okay here is what I wanted to ask:**

**Part 1:**
I am looking for a way to import / query data from several external api in to the *GCP* then store it there for further use, using the same structure as each individual api. The data is in *JSON* format.

**Part 2:**
So the stored data must be / have it's own place, container or database where I could pull data from and store that data together in a new container or database.

**Part 3:**
That stored data has to be retrieved and presented inside my app, without calling any of the external api. I want the whole app and it's functionality inside *GCP* / *Firebase*

Could this be done? And how do I approach it? I tried some things in the GCP Console, but with so many options...not sure.. use admin import/export or is that for backup only? Create a VM for every task? Containers? 
I hope someone can help me out, I'm happy to read up on things, follow tuts to get me there. But at the moment I have the feeling that I'm reading the Encyclopedia Britannica looking for a horse like creature with black and white stripes, just can't remember it's name :-)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: That all sounds possible. But it's a broad use-case, and as you've discovered the Google Cloud Platform is an even broader platform. This makes it hard to provide an answer of a reasonable length. What I recommend is to get started with the [Firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), and take this [codelab which builds an Android app with Firestore](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firestore-android/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, It might be a bit broad, but my bottleneck is only getting data from an external api, inside the cloud and go from there. I did some reading earlier and closest thing I found to suit my needs was https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api. Just not sure if it's the right one to go with it, seeing all the options :)

Comment: The codelabs shows how to read data from Firestore from an Android device. Just try it. Firebase is free to get started with, and taking the codelab is probably the fastest way for you to find out whether Firestore is what you're looking for.

Comment: Hmm that is not my problem from an Android device to Firestore and vice versa. My api is hosted somewhere else, I want Firestore/Firebase to pull data from my external api, store it in a seperate database in Firebase and use that one only as a datasource for the Android app.

Comment: There is no automatic way to pull data from an external API, since every API is different. You'll have to write code for that.

Comment: No you don't have to do that, since this api is like I said in JSON format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part 1: Use [Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/) to query data from external APIs.

Part 2: Use [Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/) to store your data by [connecting from App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine).

Part 3: Access Cloud SQL to retrieve the data from your app.